# Calculating SHA1 hash algorithm in PowerShell V2.0

Tags: algorithm, powershell, hash, powershell-2.0, sha1

Is it possible to calculate a SHA-1 hash in PowerShell V2.0?

The only information I can find online is with PowerShell V4.0.

Comment: In modern PowerShell, you can use `Get-FileHash -a SHA1 /file/path/file.exe` - see also: `Get-Help Get-FileHash` for help and a list of algorithms supported. It seems that the current default is `SHA256`, which is the most common used for website download checksums.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I can't remember back in PowerShell V2 days if .NET 3.5 was typically installed too. I think it's the case.

You can always try the following and see if it works:

```
$file = 'd:\scripts\sha1.ps1'

$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
[System.BitConverter]::ToString( $sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)))
```

Replace the value of `$file` with the name of a file you have.

Comment: Just a note to people trying this on large files like IOS's : `Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "The file is too long. This operation is currently limiited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size."`

Comment: It's probably better to use [`File.OpenRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of trying to load the entire file into memory at once. [`HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload for `Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible as it is part of NET 2.0.  In fact, the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) use the .NET hash support to implement the [`Get-Hash`](https://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/Src/Pscx/Commands/IO/GetHashCommand.cs) command.  Version 2.1.1 installs and runs on PowerShell V2.

Comment: Cheers for that! useful to know, but unfortunately i'm unable to upgrade powershell in any way shape or form.