# Powershell V2.0 SHA1 Calculation

Tags: loops, powershell, hash, powershell-2.0, sha1

[I posted a question on Monday about how I can calculate SHA1 hash within powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232146/calculating-sha1-hash-algorithm-powershell-v2-0).
The resultant code was as follows:

```
$file = 'C:\Zip\File.zip'

$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider 
[System.BitConverter]::ToString( $sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)))
```

This code works perfectly and does what I need it to do, but at the moment I have to specify the file I want the SHA1 hash to be calculated for. Is there any way I can get it to calculate the hashes for each files within that 'zip' folder.

I've been attempting to do this for the last two days by using a loop etc, and I just haven't moved anywhere. It doesn't help that my PowerShell skills are appalling.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've already made an attempt, show your code and someone can probably show you where you went wrong. Saying "why doesn't this work" without showing the code is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you just want to

1. Get a list of all files within `C:\Zip\` and
2. Apply that snippet of code to each of them.

You want to look into using ForEach loops (can also be expressed in shortened-form, for use with piping, like so: `$var | % {<#do this for each #>}`).
You can read more about ForEach loops on all over the internet - two sites I have great luck with for researching PowerShell topics are [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) and the [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach.aspx). I'd suggest checking them out, and reading up.

This should be a good start:

```
$zips = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Zip\' -Filter *.zip
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider 

foreach ($file in $zips) {
    $return = "" | Select Name, Hash

    $return.name = $file.Name
    $return.hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)))

    Write-Output $return
}
```

Comment: Ok thankyou, i'll do some reading into foreach loops, looks like im going to need them for a lot of things. Cheers!

Comment: I have run this, and it comes up with an error on each one of the zip files stating: 
_italic_Cannot find an overload for "ComputeHash" and the argument count: "1". At C:\Users\X\X\test.ps1:8 char:66
+    $return.hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash <<<< ([System.IO.File]))
+    CategoryInfo    : NotSpecified: (:) []. MethodException
+    FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest_italic_

Do you have any understanding on what this may be?

Comment: There must have been a typo, because i was going across two systems. Re-typed it and it works fine now :) Thanks again!