# Get-FileHash command in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

Can we run Get-FileHash command in powershell 2.0?

We can use Get-FileHash in powershell 5.0 nut unable to in powershell 2.0. How can we solve the problem to make Get-FileHash work in 2.0?
If the Get-HashFile command is made to run in powershell 2.0 we get the below error:

Get-HashFile "C:*.iso" -Algorithm SHA384 | Format-List
Error : The term "Get-FileHash" is not recognised as name of the cmdlet,function,script file or operable program

Comment: take a look at this ... >>> Calculating SHA1 hash algorithm in PowerShell V2.0 - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232146/calculating-sha1-hash-algorithm-in-powershell-v2-0 <<<

Comment: Upgrade your devices to PowerShell 5.1.  It is a serious security risk to still be using PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-FileHash isn't available in V2.

You can alternatively try some port of Get-FileHash in Powershell V2 like GetHash.
Here are the links to the same:

- https://gist.github.com/jaredcatkinson/7d561b553a04501238f8e4f061f112b7

  > Get-Hash is a PowerShell Version 2 port of Get-FileHash that supports
  >   hashing files, as well as, strings. This is the actual item used to
  >   calculate the hash. This value will support [Byte[]] or
  >   [System.IO.Stream] objects. Specifies the path to a file to hash.
- https://gist.github.com/stvnrs/aefcabe16dc3f69f328ed0c16e0b81cb

Let me know if these works.

Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.